# Redirect ZeroMQ PUB socket to STDIO to a local TCP socket using C#

Tags: c#, sockets, zeromq

This is probably going to sound very stupid so please bear with me.

My goal is to be able to use the Docker API attach functionality like a TCP socket, so I can use it to achieve something like an SSH or kubectl port forwarding.

I have a library `Docker.DotNet` that provides a way to get the stdio streams from the Docker API, but no functionality like `kubectl port-forward`. I would like to be able to leverage the ability to attach to stdio to use it like `port-forward`.

This works for port-forwarding HTTP traffic (adapted from `kubectl` Windows client):

```
            var createContainerResponse = await _dockerClient.Containers.CreateContainerAsync(new CreateContainerParameters
            {
                Image = "nginx",
                Cmd = new List<string>() { },
                AttachStdin = false,
                AttachStdout = false,
                AttachStderr = false,
                HostConfig = new HostConfig() {},
                ExposedPorts = new Dictionary<string, EmptyStruct>
                {
                    {
                        "80/tcp",
                        new EmptyStruct()
                    }
                }
            });

            var nginxId = createContainerResponse.ID;

            var started = await _dockerClient.Containers.StartContainerAsync(nginxId, new ContainerStartParameters());

            var inspectResponse = await _dockerClient.Containers.InspectContainerAsync(nginxId);
            var ip = inspectResponse.NetworkSettings.IPAddress;

            var socatContainerResponse = await _dockerClient.Containers.CreateContainerAsync(
                new CreateContainerParameters
                {
                    Image = "alpine/socat",
                    Cmd = new List<string>
                    {
                        "STDIO",
                        $"TCP-CONNECT:{ip}:80"
                    },
                    AttachStdin = true,
                    AttachStderr = true,
                    AttachStdout = true,
                    OpenStdin = true,
                    Tty = false,

                });

            var socatid = socatContainerResponse.ID;

            var stdio = await _dockerClient.Containers.AttachContainerAsync(socatid, false,
                new ContainerAttachParameters() {Stdout = true, Stream = true, Stdin = true, Stderr = true});
            
            await _dockerClient.Containers.StartContainerAsync(socatid, new ContainerStartParameters());


            
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Loopback;
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1213);  
            Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);  
            listener.Listen(100);

            Socket handler = null;

            // Note this will only accept a single connection
            var accept = Task.Run(async () => {
                while (true) {
                    handler = listener.Accept();
                    var bytes = new byte[4096];
                    while (true) {  
                        int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                        await stdio.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytesRec, default);
                        if (bytesRec == 0 || Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec).IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {  
                            break;  
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            var copy = Task.Run(async () => {
                var buff = new byte[4096];
                while (true)
                {
                    var read = await stdio.ReadOutputAsync(buff, 0, 4096, default);
                    handler.Send(buff, read.Count, 0);
                }
            });

            await accept;
            await copy;
            if (handler != null) {
                handler.Close();
            }
            listener.Close();
```

If I run this, it will reliably forward local port 1213 to the container port 80, using `socat`.

However, if I try to do the same with `pyzmq`, it does not work. What happens is that nothing ever gets written out to the socket. Also, it appears that `listener.Accept` is being called over and over again. My client code is very simple:

```
import sys
import zmq
import time

port = '5556'

# Socket to talk to server
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

socket.connect ('tcp://myhost:1213')

socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'output')
x = socket.recv_string()
print(x)
```

It gets stuck at `recv_string` because nothing is ever written to the socket, even though my producer is definitely constantly producing strings. If I instead replace `myhost:1213` with the actual port that I am trying to redirect, it works.

If you can't tell I am a newb... so what is different about HTTP vs ZeroMQ PUB/SUB where the example code works for HTTP forwarding but not (seemingly simpler) ZeroMQ PUB/SUB protocol over TCP?

Comment: Well, not seeing the PUB-side processing, hard to tell. I would start with (a) complete the MCVE-definition here, (b) start with SUB-side subscribe to `""`-string (~ everything ) (c) use rather explicit IP-address, avoiding `localhost` symbol translation (d) if needed, adding `zmq_socket_monitor()`-diagnostics on either side of the `PUB / SUB`-relation, so as to see all ISO-OSI-L2-level events and more - finally, not known to me, is the used port-forwarding sure to be transparent port-level forwarding, or is it a protocol-Gateway, capable of HTTP*-forwards, yet not a binary-transparent pFWD?